# SHAP value can explain right?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, xgboost, shap

I face a problem with using SHAP value to interpret the Tree-based model.
(https://github.com/slundberg/shapsd)
First, I have input around 30 features and I have 2 features that have high positive correlation between them.
After that, I train the XGBoost model(python) and look at SHAP values of 2 features the SHAP values have negative correlation.

Could you all explain to me, why the output SHAP values between 2 features don't have the correlation the same as input correlation? and I can trust that output of SHAP or not?

## =========================

The correlation between input: 0.91788
The correlation between SHAP values: -0.661088

2 features are
1) Pupulation in province and
2) Number of family in province.

Model Performance
Train AUC: 0.73
Test AUC: 0.71

Scatter plot
[Input scatter plot (x: Number of family in province, y: Pupulation in province)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3QOS.png)
[SHAP values output scatter plot (x: Number of family in province, y: Pupulation in province)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgd3M.png)

Comment: Thank you for your question. You might have luck getting answers to this type of question at the Data Science Stack Exchange site  https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thank you jeffhale.

Answer (score 1):

You can have correlated variables that have opposite effects on the model output.

As an example, let's take the case of predicting risk of mortality given two features: 'age' and 'trips to doctors'. Although these two variables are positively correlated, their effects are different. All other things held constant, a higher 'age' leads to a higher risk of mortality (according to the trained model). And a higher number of 'trips to doctor' leads to a smaller risk of mortality.

XGBoost (and SHAP) isolates the effect of these two correlated variables by conditioning on the other variable: e.g. splitting on 'trips to doctors' feature, after splitting on 'age' feature. Assumption here is that they are not perfectly correlated.

Answer (score 0):

XGBoost is not a linear model, i.e. the relationship between the input features X and the predictions y is not linear. SHAP values build a linear explanation model of y. Therefore, it is very much expected that the correlation between input features and their SHAP values do not match.